# Where can I download the Samantha Field Control System?

Tags: nxt

Could someone please provide a download link? It seems that all traces of the program has disappeared from the internet, and I need this to get my robot moving wirelessly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This guy](http://john.toebes.com/) appears to have used the Samantha Field control system and has a [download section](http://john.toebes.com/projects/first/46-samantha.html#downloads).